# Swift @objc protocol - distinguish optional methods with similar signature

Tags: swift, option-type, swift-protocols

Let's say we have a protocol in Swift:

```
@objc protocol FancyViewDelegate {
  optional func fancyView(view: FancyView, didSelectSegmentAtIndex index: Int)
  optional func fancyView(view: FancyView, shouldHighlightSegmentAtIndex index: Int) -> Bool
}
```

Note that both methods are optional and have the same prefix signature.

Now our `FancyView` class looks like this:

```
class FancyView: UIView {
  var delegate: FancyViewDelegate?

  private func somethingHappened() {
    guard let delegateImpl = delegate?.fancyView else {
      return
    }

    let idx = doALotOfWorkToFindTheIndex()

    delegateImpl(self, idx)
  }
}
```

The compiler jumps in our face:

[image]

We could change `somethingHappened()` to this:

```
private func somethingHappened() {
  let idx = doALotOfWorkToFindTheIndex()

  delegate?.fancyView?(self, didSelectSegmentAtIndex: idx)
}
```

However, as you can see we risk doing a lot of work only to throw away the index afterwards, because the delegate does not implement the optional method.

The question is: How do we `if let` or `guard let` bind the implementation of two optional methods with a similar prefix signature.

Comment: I would still use respondsToSelector and call relevant method if it is supported.

Answer (score 0):

First, your objective C protocol needs to confirm to   NSObjectProtocol to ensure we can introspect if it supports a given method.

Then when we want to call specific method, check if that method is supported by conforming object and if yes, then perform necessary computations needed to call that method. I tried this code for instance-

```
  @objc protocol FancyViewDelegate : NSObjectProtocol {
      optional func fancyView(view: UIView, didSelectSegmentAtIndex index: Int)
      optional func fancyView(view: UIView, shouldHighlightSegmentAtIndex index: Int) -> Bool
    }


    class FancyView: UIView {
      var delegate: FancyViewDelegate?

      private func somethingHappened() {
        if delegate?.respondsToSelector("fancyView:didSelectSegmentAtIndex") == true {
          let idx :Int  = 0 //Compute the index here
          delegate?.fancyView!(self, didSelectSegmentAtIndex: idx)
        }
      }
    }
```